# sshexec command - ftp get as parametes

Tags: ant, ssh, ftp

In my code am using something like

```
   <sshexec host="somehost"
username="dude"
password="yo"
command="ftp_download"/>

<ftp action="get" server="server_todownload" userid="user" password="aaa" remotedir="dowload/dir">
        <fileset dir="${installerdirectory}"><include name="${file_name}"/></fileset>
    </ftp>
```

In "command" of sshexec how i can pass the ftp action as parameters??
is there any example or document is there to get more knowledge??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to:

- ssh to another machine, and
- download something on that machine using ftp.

I think you misunderstood something. `<sshexec>` is a task that sshes to a machine and executes a command on that machine. The command it executes must exist on that machine. For example, your code:

```
<sshexec host="somehost" username="dude" password="yo" command="ftp_download"/>
```

There must be a command named `ftp_download` existing on `somehost` or your `<sshexec>` will fail. You can't use an ant task in your local build file as a parameter because `<sshexec>` doesn't work in this way at all.

Suggestion:

You can put the `ftp` task in an ant build file, and deploy it to the remote machine (you can use `scp` task) before `sshexec`. In `sshexec`'s command, you write `ant -f  path_to_build_file ftp_target`. You need to ensure that there is ant on that machine.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Basically i need to run the script from client side, which will ssh to target machine and ddownload some file and do the execution. Sorry i couldnt able to understand your suggestion. can you explain me more? btw the target machine has ant.

Comment: Btw i can able to use pssh instead of sshexec?? something like this..  <exec executable="cmd">  <arg value="/c"/> <arg value="plink -pw ${pwd} ${user}@${host} ${command}"/> </exec>... if this is possible then how to pass ftp into command arguments???

Comment: @coolgokul first of all, as far as I know, the Linux ftp commandline is an interactive app, which is not possible for `<sshexec>` to use. My suggestion is very clear: you write another ant build file in which you use `<ftp>` task to download files, and deploy this build file to that machine using `<scp>` task, and then use `<sshexec>` to execute the build file on that machine.

Comment: @coolgokul let me clearify: when you want to use ant to execute some command on a remote machine with `<sshexc>`, the command needs to meet the following requirements: 1. it exists on the remote machine and it is in the PATH for your ssh login. 2. it is not interactive. If the command has an interactive shell, it is very very hard for you to write ant codes to interact with it. This also applies to `<exec>`.